# Which word to use for less well known brands?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am doing Customer Support and I need to tell my user that their phone is from "a less well known" brand (e.g. from Xiaomi instead of Apple, Samsung). Which words to use in this courtesy context?

Comment: Your title and context contradict each other. Are you looking for a word that means "less known brands" or not ?

Comment: It depends on your reason for mentioning it. For example, you'd likely answer differently depending on whether the customer asked, "Is it a well known brand?" or "Why are you holding less stock of this cheap phone?"

Comment: Thank you guys, I think off brand is perfectly fine. I am doing Customer Support via email. 
@Mari-LouA sorry, fixed the question!
BiscuitBoy I am looking for a word that means "less known"

Comment: @boh Why do you need to tell your customers this? Is it to explain that it is more difficult to fix their phone?

Comment: Are you replying to customers' complaint emails? How would you know which mobile they have otherwise? You can have a low-end model from a famous brand, it's just a less expensive version. If you're telling customers their phone is an [*off-brand*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/off-brand) they could be ticked off, it's like saying to someone: "Oh, you can't afford a *real* iPhone so you've got that model instead".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell the person that their phone is "[off-brand](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/off-brand?s=t)."  It means the brand isn't a well-known.

Comment: Yeah, but that could have a pejorative connotation in a "courtesy context". *Off-brand: an unknown, unpopular, or inferior brand of retail product.* To OP: Why not just say 'not well-known brand' or a "lesser known brand"?

Comment: It depends on the tone. Off-brand seens a perfect fit to me, with a neutral voice.

Comment: The term "off-brand" is not pejorative.  Just like many things, it could be insinuated as pejorative if used with a certain tone, but it isn't innately pejorative.  Example:  "Phones like iPhone and Android, as well as off-brand phones, have improved in overall resiliency to the elements."  There is nothing pejorative about "off-brand."

Comment: But the OP is using the expression in an email, there is no tone of voice in emails.

Comment: I have read: "I need to tell my user". Where is the email mention?

Answer (score 1):

I asked my baker for a [croissant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croissant). "Butter or ordinary", she said with a depreciative tone on the last word. I bought the butter one... I propose **ordinary** or **generic**. [Generic brands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_brand) seem to be used in supermarkets.

But [off-brand](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/299486/which-word-to-use-for-less-well-known-brands/299496#299496) by @Benjamin Harman is excellent.

EDIT: as the answer above is checked as the best (deserved), let me add options for the sake of completeness: for smartphones, *cheap* and *low-cost* are quite related to the fame of a brand. Fuels exist in *regular* and premium. *Standard* was my last option.

Comment: By definition, a croissant is made with a lot of butter.  What could "ordinary" mean in this context, since an ordinary croissant IS buttery?

Comment: Generally, vegetable oil. Could be better (not the taste) for vegans

Comment: Then it wouldn't really be a croissant.  I guess that vegans eat things that they call burgers that aren't really burgers, but that's a whole different issue.  Plus, it wouldn't be the ordinary type; it would be the exception.

Comment: In [The Best Croissant in Paris](http://www.davidlebovitz.com/2007/02/the-best-croiss/) you can read: "Whatever pâtisserie you visit, be sure to only ingest a true croissant au beurre, which has that unmistakable smell of deeply-toasted, caramelized-crunchy French beurre. Stay away from croissants ordinaires". Whether we like it or not, the concept exists

Comment: .........Sacre bleu!

Comment: Unfortunately, "les croissants ordinaires" are more common that "sacre bleu" (which is an equivalent of "darned": holy swear words in disguise)

Answer (score 1):

The OP could inform customers that they are using a ***low-end*** brand or a *low-end model*

**[low-end](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/low-end)** <sub><sup>(The Free Dictionary)</sup></sub>
1. Cheapest in a line of merchandise
2. Informal Of, relating to, or intended for low-income consumers; downscale

Otherwise, the OP could simply say that the customer's phone  is **not a top brand**. I believe that phrasing is the least equivocal, less offensive (or derogative) and the easiest to understand.

> A: I have a problem with my cell phone, it's a  *blah, blah*
>   B: OK, it's **not a top brand**, but we can still help you.
>   B: OK, it's a **low-end model** (or brand), but we can still help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Low-end** or **off-brand** connotes something that is cheap and is of low quality.  **Generic** means that the item does not carry a brand at all; i.e a box of tissues that is marked "Tissues".  **Ordinary** just means the same as any other; i.e. an **ordinary** can opener just opens cans, while a deluxe model may have a corkscrew or a knife sharpener included.

You were on the right track to begin with.  It's fine to say a **lesser-known brand.** (Note: **not** a **"less well known brand."**

Answer (score -3):

Though this is primarily used in music industry, **indie** is applicable here also